# Getting a import com.google.gson.Gson cannot be resolved;

Tags: java

I got some sampke code from the internet that has the following 2 lines on top
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
whitch gives me a cannot br resolved error, which I'm assuming I must some how add those libraries,
Does anybody know how to do this or could point me to a toturiol?

Comment: Would it be similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774340/how-do-i-install-the-gson-module-in-java)?

I'm guessing the .jar is found [here](https://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.google.code.gson%7Cgson%7C2.4%7Cjar)

Comment: Use this [maven dependency](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.3.1) or download jar from there and use the steps mentioned in the answer from @Foleosy comment.